# Xamarin Listview data loading is slow on the Android side

Tags: android, web-services, listview, xamarin, navigation

For example, when I want to open the city list, when I tap on the menu, the other page is loaded with the listview web service. On the ios side, the transition to the next page is fast. There is a slight wait on the Android side. What is the reason?

Page Load this code

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    LoadItems();
                    activity.IsVisible = false;
                    activity.IsRunning = false;
                    activity.IsEnabled = false;
                    break;
                case Device.Android:
                    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
                    {
                        LoadItems();
                        activity.IsVisible = false;
                        activity.IsRunning = false;
                        activity.IsEnabled = false;
                        return false;
                    });
                    break;

            }
        });

public async void LoadItems()
    {
        Call Web Service
    }
```

Comment: you can try to set a listview [caching strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/performance) to improve performance.

Comment: CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: whether there are many images in ListView? if yes, you can try to use FFImageLoading, it need less memory usage.